# Print SparkSession Config Options

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

When I start pyspark, a SparkSession is automatically generated and available as 'spark'. I would like to print/view the details of the spark session but am having a lot of difficulty accessing these parameters.

Pyspark auto creates a SparkSession. This can be created manually using the following code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("PythonSQL")\ 
        .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value")\ 
        .getOrCreate()
```

I would like to view/print the appname and config options. The reason I would like to see these is as a result of another issue that I am experiencing which this may shed light on.

Answer (score 6):

Application name can be accessed using `SparkContext`:

```
spark.sparkContext.appName
```

Configuration is accessible using `RuntimeConfig`:

```
from py4j.protocol import Py4JError

try: 
   spark.conf.get("some.conf")
except Py4JError as e:
   pass
```

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated!

Comment: I am glad to hear that. If it resolved the issue please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer.